# How to add arrow bootstrap navbar brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How do you add an arrow using css to the navbar brand (see image example)

[image]

The arrow should not be visible when in mobile view.

The following doesn't work - clearly I'm not the best at css.

```
 .navbar-default {
        .navbar-brand {
                position: relative; 
                float: left;
                margin-right:30px;
                color: @navbar-default-brand-color;
                &:hover,
                &:focus {
                    color: @navbar-default-brand-hover-color;
                    background-color: @navbar-default-brand-hover-bg;
                }

                &:after {
                      content: " ";
                      display: block;
                      width: 0;
                      height: 0;
                      border-top: 19px solid transparent;
                      border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
                      border-left: 12px solid @brand-secondary;
                      position: absolute;
                      top: 50%;
                      margin-top: -19px;
                      left: 100%;
                      z-index: 3;
                }


                &:before {
                      content: " ";
                      display: block;
                      width: 0;
                      height: 0;
                      border-top: 19px solid transparent;
                      border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
                      border-left: 12px solid white;
                      position: absolute;
                      top: 50%;
                      margin-top: -19px;
                      margin-left: 1px;
                      left: 100%;
                      z-index: 3;
                }


               @media (max-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {


               }
        }
    }
```

the html is as follows

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
         <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
     </div>
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
               <a href="#">Getting started</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">Components</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">Javascript</a>
            </li>
             <li>
               <a href="#">Customize</a>
            </li>
     </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Update: I've managed to get it working using the before and after css. How do I overide this css with the media query i.e whats the css that goes inside the media query to remove it on a mobile device?

Comment: Did you try using @media in your css?

Comment: could you make a fiddle? the code above doesn't give us much to work with.

Answer (score 2):

have created a small fiddle with example code of how to do this for list items. It can be edited slightly and re-applied to your code to achieve the desired affect.

It's all about the `:before` and `:after` selectors.

http://jsfiddle.net/dgc6ajbL/

Comment: I only want it applied to the navbar brand - not the list items. I've tried the breadcrumb example which I found on bootsnip but I dont quite understand how to apply it to the navbar brand.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer (the CSS) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @ozzii Yeah. It's actually alot harder to implement than I realised when I posted the code. This is the closest I can get at the moment as i'm heading out. I hope it's of some help.

http://jsfiddle.net/ge7v7g89/1/